# Как заставить выйти значение переменной из функции?

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть:

```
<?php
   $abc=4;
   echo $abc;

   function aaa(){
      $abc=10;
      echo $abc;
   };

   aaa();
   echo $abc;
?>
```

Этот код выводит 4 10 4. Как заставить в конце выйти значение переменной из функции?

Comment: что значит "выйти" из функции?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а то и значит. Что бы значение переменной обьявленной внутри функции было доступно за её пределами.

Comment: так у вас такая же переменная глобальная есть, происходит перезапись

Comment: то, что объявлено в функции не может быть доступно из вне. ...в другую сторону - можно...но не наоборот

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и как быть?

Comment: непонятно что тебе нужно вообще...

Comment: как вариант, присвоить новой переменной, объявленной снаружи результат выполнения функции

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич как?

Comment: ответ 3 пункт ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты хочешь, чтобы после выполнения функции значение переменной `$abc` было таким, каким его присвоили в функции, то есть три способа:

1 вариант - обращение к глобальной переменной (плохой способ):

```
$abc = 4;
echo $abc;

function aaa(){
    global $abc;

    $abc = 10;
    echo $abc;
}

aaa();
echo $abc;
```

2 вариант - передача по ссылке:

```
$abc = 4;
echo $abc;

function bbb(&$setByLink){ 
    $setByLink = 10;
    echo $setByLink;
}

bbb($abc);
echo $abc;
```

3 вариант - возвращать из функции значение, которое присваивать переменной:

```
$abc = 4;
echo $abc;

function ccc($myvar){ 
    // что-то делаем
    $tmp = 10;
    echo $tmp;
    return $tmp;
}
$abc = ccc($abc);
echo $abc;
```

Comment: А передача по ссылке это не манипулирование глобальной переменной ?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, ты об этом спрашивал?

```
<?php
$abc=4;
echo $abc;
function aaa(&$abc) {
    $abc=10;
    echo $abc;
};

aaa($abc);
echo $abc;
?>
```